# Wordpress htaccess not a directory rule keep firing anyway

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a strange problem with a site i installed on my server, the same exact code works elsewhere so i'm stuck here trying to figure out what is not working.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is the standard Wordpress htaccess. Technically, the "!-d" rule should allow me to list or access any directory but in this install, it's not the case.

I have a "admin" folder and wordpress keeps kicking in and handling the admin url as "wp-admin" but thats not what i want. I already have other servers where i have a custom "admin" folder mixed with wordpress and it launches fine but something strange here seems to be hapenning.

What we have done:

- Disable the rewrite engine, wordpress turns off the folder responds
- Disable/Reenable the rewrite engine (to flush possible existing rules) nope
- Tried to add "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin", doesn't work, WP still kicks in

Can you guys suggest anything else?

Comment: There could be many reasons. Do you have mod_speling active? Is wordpress in a separate directory? Is DirectoryIndex active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing we found out that wordpress was catching all error messages even the 401 on our server. It kept showing 404 because thats the only rendered error by Wordpress.

To this end, we just put a

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

In the folder we were trying to access and blam! all of it works now!

I hope this can help others!